# Zero to One then ask for another value from zero to one

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, user-input

I'm very new to python and I'm still confused as to how to do this:

I constructed a program to use a while loop where i can get values from 0 to 1 through this:

```
while True:
  x= input("Enter a number from 0 to 1: ")
  try:
    if float(x)>=0 and float(x)<=1:
      print("Congrats!")
      break
    elif float(x) < 0:
      print("This number is negative")
    elif float(x) > 1:
      print("This number is too high!")
    else:
      print("Try again")
  except ValueError:
    print("This is not a number")
```

And another program where I ask through a while loop using `while again == 'y' or 'Y':`

But I can't seem to get a combination of both. **I want a program that first gets a value from 0 to 1, and then ask if the user wants to input another number through y or n.**

I tried this to no avail:

```
def ask_input():
  while again == 'y' or 'Y':
    while True:
      x= input("Enter a number from 0 to 1: ")
      try:
        if float(x)>=0 and float(x)<=1:
          print("Congrats!")
          again = input('do you want again? y or n: ')
          break
        elif float(x) < 0:
          print("This number is negative")
        elif float(x) > 1:
          print("This number is too high!")
        else:
          print("Try again")
      except ValueError:
        print("This is not a number")

ask_input()
```

Also how to put this all into a list? Filled with numbers that range from 0 to 1?

Comment: `while again == 'y' or  again == 'Y'`

Comment: Or `while again.lower() == 'y'`

Comment: Explicitly catch the exception or exceptions, catching all is very bad practice.